# Not getting 'gulp-version-number' to work

Tags: gulp, version-numbering

First time looking at gulp and having the project land on my lap, and of-course not getting it to work.

I need to get a version number on the files and not getting 'gulp-version-number' to work - the old code does, it just "jumps over" the versionNumber command.

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var concat = require('gulp-concat');
var uglify = require('gulp-uglify');
var rename = require('gulp-rename');
var sourcemaps = require('gulp-sourcemaps');
var minifycss = require('gulp-minify-css');
var versionNumber = require('gulp-version-number');

var jsDest = 'ui/dist/js/';

var versionConfig = {
    value: '%MDS%',
    append: {
        key: 'v',
        to: ['css', 'js']
    },
    output: {
        file: 'version.json'
    }
};

gulp.task('scripts', function () {
    return gulp.src('ui/js/site/*.js')
        .pipe(concat('site.js'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(jsDest))
        .pipe(rename('site.min.js'))
        .pipe(versionNumber(versionConfig)) //<-- not doing notin'
        .pipe(uglify())
        .pipe(gulp.dest(jsDest));
});

//and the same for SASS/CSS
```

Environment is Visual Studio 2015.
Glad for any input!

(Next step is to modify the references to the files with version nbr...)